# Is there a reason why VectorLength returns size_t while Vector::size returns uoffset_t?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

This sometimes causes problems with 64-Bit compilation. If there is no special reason, I think it would be better to have a consistent index type for VectorLength() and Vector::size().

In this example the call to print_first_n_of_inventory with VectorLength requires a cast.

```
#include <flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h>
#include <tests/monster_test_generated.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace flatbuffers;
using namespace MyGame::Example;

void print_first_n_of_inventory(const Vector<uint8_t> * pInventory, uoffset_t n)
{
    for (uoffset_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        auto val = pInventory->Get(i);
        std::cout << val << "\n";
    }
}

int main(int, char * argv[])
{
    auto * pMonster = GetMonster(argv[1]);
    auto * pInventory = pMonster->inventory();

    print_first_n_of_inventory(pInventory, 2);
    print_first_n_of_inventory(pInventory, pInventory->size());

    // warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'flatbuffers::uoffset_t', possible loss of data
    print_first_n_of_inventory(pInventory, VectorLength(pInventory));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `VectorLength` checks that the supplied pointer is not `nullptr` and converts the `uoffset_t` returned by `size()` to `size_t`. Possibly to make it easier to use in non-flatbuffer contexts where a `size_t` is expected - but it seems unnecessary as you've noticed. It'd be better to use `uoffset_t` in both. I'd use the member function `size()` directly when I'm sure `pInventory` is not `nullptr` and a `uoffset_t` (which is always `uint32_t`) is wanted. Or add this: `template<typename T> static inline auto MyVectorLength(const Vector<T>* v) { return v ? v->size() : 0U; }` and use that instead.

Comment: My replacement function template should have been: `template<typename T> static inline auto MyVectorLength(const flatbuffers::Vector<T>* v) { return v ? v->size() : 0U; }` - I forgot the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is unfortunate, but `uoffset_t` is the native type of how the length is stored in FlatBuffers, which is always 32-bit. It seemed best to expose this native type than to convert to `size_t` for the user, as that would cause double conversion in the case where 32-bits would actually be desirable.

Comment: Do you think this can and should be changed?
It could led to a different type deduced with auto type deduction or template code but otherwise should be implicitly converted to size_t like now inside the function.